# Why is this code looping through urls properly, but not retrieving data from those urls

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nltk

in an attempt to get the reviews from each proceeding page i am getting only the reviews for the first page. however, each proceeding url is being looped properly, the reviews are just not being scraped.

i imported all necessary packages.

my code is:

```
for i in range(0,700,5):
    url2 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g35805-d87576-Reviews-or' + str(i) + '-Travelodge_Hotel_Downtown_Chicago-Chicago_Illinois.html'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    #opens URL in chrome
    browser.get(url2)
    print(url2)
    #Stalls load to make it look like human browsing
    time.sleep(5) # seconds
    html = browser.page_source
    #create soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for r in soup.find_all('div', 'reviewSelector'):
        Review = r.p.text
        #splits up list by word
        words = word_tokenize(review)
        #noramlizes words in list to lowercase
        clean_words = [word.lower() for word in words if word not in set(string.punctuation)]
        #stopwords object
        english_stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        #gets the words; not including stopwords
        clean_words = [word for word in clean_words if word not in english_stops]
        #Make an easier wordnetlemmatizer object for ease of use
        wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        #reduce variation in the words
        lemma_list = []
        lemma_list = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in clean_words]
        #append reviews to the list
        reviews.append(lemma_list)
        print(lemma_list)
```

im using selenium and webdriver.chrome() to open the webpages.

Comment: where is your `list` "reviews" to `.append` to?

Comment: I didn't include that in the code- my apologies. Above the code i have reviews = [ ] @jk622

Comment: It is scraping the data.  If you comment out everything below `Review` and `print(Review)` you can see that the data is being scraped for each url.  I suggest you narrow down your question by providing a [mcve]